# How to add a footer in default MainLayout.razor?

Tags: css, blazor, blazor-client-side

What is the correct CSS to add a footer in the default Blazor layout? - I have tried some approach without success. I appreciate your help.

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            Anything
        </div>

        <div class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </div>
        <!-- ** How to make it stay fixed in the bottom? -->
        <footer>
            Anything, @(DateTime.Today.Year)
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is my complete solution for `.NET 6` Blazor templates for both **fixed footer** and **sticky footer** that uses Bootstrap 5.
It also includes the login display in the header.

Just posting it here so someone might find it useful.

**Note:** What you only need to add is inside these lines (I have included everything here just for completeness):

```
/*Code I added - Start*/
/*Code I added - End*/
```

### Final look

For Desktop screens:
[image]

For Mobile screens:

[image]

### Code

`Navmenu.razor` looks like this:

```
<div class="top-row ps-3 pe-3 navbar navbar-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
            <span class="fs-4">Handy Man's Tool</span>
        </a>
        <button title="Navigation menu" class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <nav class="flex-column">
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter">
                <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="repairs/new">
                <span class="oi oi-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></span> New Repair
            </NavLink>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>

@code {
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;

    private string? NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }
}
```

`Navmenu.razor.css` looks like this:

```
.navbar-toggler {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.top-row {
    height: 3.5rem;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.navbar-brand {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.oi {
    width: 2rem;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    top: -2px;
}

.nav-item {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

    .nav-item:first-of-type {
        padding-top: 1rem;
    }

    .nav-item:last-of-type {
        padding-bottom: 1rem;
    }

    .nav-item ::deep a {
        color: #d7d7d7;
        border-radius: 4px;
        height: 3rem;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        line-height: 3rem;
    }

        .nav-item ::deep a.active {
            background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
            color: white;
        }

        .nav-item ::deep a:hover {
            background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
            color: white;
        }

@media (min-width: 641px) {
    .navbar-toggler {
        display: none;
    }

    .collapse {
         /*Never collapse the sidebar for wide screens*/
        display: block;
    }
}
```

`MainLayout.razor` looks like this:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<PageTitle>Handy Man's Tool</PageTitle>
<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4 logindisplay">
            <span>Hi, User</span>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Log Out</button>
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>

        <div class="bottom-row px-4">
            <a href="">
                <img src="/images/logo-black.png" width="40"/>
                <span class="fs-4">HMT</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </main>
</div>
```

### Fixed footer css

`MainLayout.razor.css` looks like this:

```
.page {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; 
    /*Code I added - Start*/
    max-height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    /*Code I added - End*/
}

main {
    flex: 1;
    /*Code I added - Start*/
    overflow-y: auto;
    /*Code I added - End*/
}

.sidebar {
    /*background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(5, 39, 103) 0%, #3a0647 70%);*/ /*Original code*/
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(5, 39, 103) 0%, #000000 70%);
}

.top-row {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d5d5;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    height: 3.5rem;
    /*Code I added - Start*/
    max-height: 3.5rem;
    /*Code I added - End*/
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

    .top-row ::deep a, .top-row .btn-link {
        white-space: nowrap;
        margin-left: 1.5rem;
    }

    .top-row a:first-child {
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }

/*Code I added - Start*/
.bottom-row {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-top: 1px solid #d6d5d5;
    height: 3.5rem;
    max-height: 3.5rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100vw;
}

/*Select all a elements where parent is a .bottom-row*/
.bottom-row > a {
    display: flex;
    color: rgb(33, 37, 41);
    /*color and text-decor used to not show it as link*/
    text-decoration: none;
    /*fontsize is the same copied from navbar-brand style inside NavMenu.razor.css*/
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

/*Optionally this selector will also work: main article.content*/
main > .content {
    /*7rem comes from adding 3.5rem of top-row and 3.5rem of bottom-row*/
    height: calc(100vh - 7rem);
    max-height: calc(100vh - 7rem);
    overflow-y: auto;
}
/*Code I added - End*/

/*less than or equal to*/
/*Max-width is the maximum width at which a style will continue to be applied. 
After that, the style will STOP being applied.*/
@media (max-width: 640.98px) {
    .top-row:not(.logindisplay) {
        display: none;
    }

    .top-row.logindisplay {
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .top-row a, .top-row .btn-link {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    /*Code I added - Start*/
    .page main {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding-bottom: 3.5rem;
    }

        .page main .top-row {
            flex: 0 0 3.5rem;
        }
    /*Code I added - End*/
}

/*greater than or equal to*/
/*Min-width is the minimum width at which a style will START to be applied*/
@media (min-width: 641px) {
    .page {
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .sidebar {
        width: 250px;
        height: 100vh;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
    }

    /*Code I added - Start*/
    .bottom-row {
        left: 250px;
        width: calc(100vw - 250px);
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }
    /*Code I added - End*/

    .top-row {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .top-row, article {
        padding-left: 2rem !important;
        padding-right: 1.5rem !important;
    }
}
```

`site.css` looks like this:

```
@import url('open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css');

html, body {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    /*Code I added - Start*/
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: 100vh;
    /*Code I added - End*/
}

h1:focus {
    outline: none;
}

a, .btn-link {
    color: #0071c1;
}

.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1b6ec2;
    border-color: #1861ac;
}

.content {
    padding-top: 1.1rem;
}

.valid.modified:not([type=checkbox]) {
    outline: 1px solid #26b050;
}

.invalid {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}

.validation-message {
    color: red;
}

#blazor-error-ui {
    background: lightyellow;
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0.6rem 1.25rem 0.7rem 1.25rem;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#blazor-error-ui .dismiss {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0.75rem;
    top: 0.5rem;
}

.blazor-error-boundary {
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) no-repeat 1rem/1.8rem, #b32121;
    padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 3.7rem;
    color: white;
}

.blazor-error-boundary::after {
    content: "An error has occurred."
}
```

### Sticky footer css

Don't change anything in any other file, and only update `MainLayout.razor.css` with this:

```
.page {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    /*Code I added - Start*/
    min-height: 100vh;
    /*Code I added - End*/
}

main {
    flex: 1;
}

.sidebar {
    /*background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(5, 39, 103) 0%, #3a0647 70%);*/ /*Original code*/
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(5, 39, 103) 0%, #000000 70%);
}

.top-row {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d5d5;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    height: 3.5rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

    .top-row ::deep a, .top-row .btn-link {
        white-space: nowrap;
        margin-left: 1.5rem;
    }

    .top-row a:first-child {
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }

/*Code I added - Start*/
.bottom-row {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-top: 1px solid #d6d5d5;
    height: 3.5rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100vw;
}

/*Select all a elements where parent is a .bottom-row*/
.bottom-row > a {
    display: flex;
    color: rgb(33, 37, 41);
    /*color and text-decor used to not show it as link*/
    text-decoration: none;
    /*fontsize is the same copied from navbar-brand style inside NavMenu.razor.css*/
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

/*Optionally this selector will also work: main article.content*/
main > .content {
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin-bottom: 3.5rem;
}
/*Code I added - End*/

/*less than or equal to*/
/*Max-width is the maximum width at which a style will continue to be applied. 
After that, the style will STOP being applied.*/
@media (max-width: 640.98px) {
    .top-row:not(.logindisplay) {
        display: none;
    }

    .top-row.logindisplay {
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .top-row a, .top-row .btn-link {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}

/*greater than or equal to*/
/*Min-width is the minimum width at which a style will START to be applied*/
@media (min-width: 641px) {
    .page {
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .sidebar {
        width: 250px;
        height: 100vh;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
    }

    /*Code I added - Start*/
    .bottom-row {
        left: 250px;
        width: calc(100vw - 250px);
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }
    /*Code I added - End*/

    .top-row {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .top-row, article {
        padding-left: 2rem !important;
        padding-right: 1.5rem !important;
    }
}
```

As you can see **Sticky footer** is way more simpler than **Fixed footer**, and that's why it's my preferred way of doing footer.

Answer (score 3):

`app.css`

```
...
html, body, #app {
    height: 100vh
    max-height: 100vh;
}
...
```

Add this to `MainLayout.razor.css`

```
...
.main > footer {
    height: 3rem;
    max-height: 3rem;
}
.main > .content {
    height: calc(100vh - 6.5rem);
    max-height: calc(100vh - 6.5rem);
    overflow-y: auto;
}
...


@media (min-width: 641px) {
...
    .sidebar {
        max-height: 100vh;
        overflow-y: auto;
...
    }
```

Note: The `6.5rem` in `calc(100vh - 6.5rem)` is the sum of the default for `top-row` (`3.5rem`) + `3rem` for the footer.

Comment: Can you please post a more complete answer for .NET 6? I followed this and it didn't work for me.

Comment: Nevermind, just figured it out and posted it below. 

Answer (score 1):

I made a really simple component for fixed bottom footers. The component allows for a dynamic height.

**MainLayou.Razor**

```
<div class="page">
.
.
.
    <FooterComponent></FooterComponent>
</div>
```

The components only job is to adjust the `.page` `paddingBottom` to be equivalent to the height of the `FooterComponent`. This ensures our page content is never hidden behind the footer.

**FooterComponent.razor**

```
@using Microsoft.JSInterop

  <footer class="footer" id="footer">
    .
    .
    .
  </footer>

@code {


    [Inject] IJSRuntime JS { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
         await JS.InvokeAsync<string>("FooterResized", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this));
    }

}
```

**Supporting Javascript**

```
function FooterResized(dotnethelper) {
    function padPageElement() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("page")[0].style.paddingBottom = footerElm.offsetHeight + "px";
    }
    var footerElm = document.getElementById("footer");
    new ResizeObserver(padPageElement).observe(footerElm);
}
```

**Supporting CSS**

```
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it
Step 1.
Add this in mainlayout.razor

```
<main>
    
    
    <article class="content px-2 mb-3">
        @Body
    </article>
    <Div class="page-footer">
        <p  style="margin:5px 10px 5px 0px;">Any Text Here</p>
    </Div>
</main>
```

Step 2.
create mainlauout.razor.css and paste this

```
.page-footer {
background-color: var(--com-bg2);
border-top: 1px solid lightgray;
border-bottom: 2px solid lightgray;
border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
color: white;
text-align: right;
width:100%;
font-size:smaller;
font-style:oblique;
```

}

```
.page-footer :hover {
font-size:larger;
```

}

Hope this will help.

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted a footer in the NavMenu to show the release date of the system.  This is what worked for me.

```
<MudDrawer @bind-Open="@_drawerOpen">
        <PipelinesNavMenu />
        <MudText Color="@Color.Primary" Align="@Align.Left">Release @SystemVersion.Version</MudText> 
</MudDrawer>
```