# Blazor Project Footer Scrolls Off Page

Tags: html, css, blazor-server-side

Was not sure exactly how to title this issue. I have a Blazor Server project built from the standard template in Visual Studio. I have a footer defined in the _Layout.cshtml file. The problem I’m having is that when a page is displayed the footer does not show at the bottom until you scroll down. This happens on all pages including the home page (index.razor), the standard template counter.razor page and all the others including the ones I created. This probably has something to do with the MainLayout.razor and MainLayout.razor.css.

_Layout.cshtml looks like this:

```
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer border-top pl-3 text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2023 - MyWebsite.com - <a asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
```

The MainLayout.razor file is standard:

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>
    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4 auth">
            <LoginDisplay />
            <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>
```

and I have not changed anything in the MainLayout.razor.css file:

```
.page {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
main {
    flex: 1;
}
.sidebar {
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(5, 39, 103) 0%, #3a0647 70%);
}
.top-row {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d5d5;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    height: 3.5rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.top-row ::deep a, .top-row .btn-link {
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-left: 1.5rem;
}
.top-row a:first-child {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
@media (max-width: 640.98px) {
    .top-row:not(.auth) {
        display: none;
    }
    .top-row.auth {
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .top-row a, .top-row .btn-link {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 641px) {
    .page {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .sidebar {
        width: 250px;
        height: 100vh;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
    }
    .top-row {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .top-row, article {
        padding-left: 2rem !important;
        padding-right: 1.5rem !important;
    }
}
```

and the site.css is, I believe, from the standard template:

```
@import url('open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css');
html, body {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
...
```

What do I need to change here that will display the footer normally, i.e. no scrolling necessary?

Comment: As a start, move the footer to MainLayout.razor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a footer in default MainLayout.razor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65654999/how-to-add-a-footer-in-default-mainlayout-razor)

Comment: As per the deleted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76369034/7758804) by the OP, this is a duplicate.